# Counting application usage in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone help me determine how to count how many times an application has been used in Android?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to write a launcher or are you trying to promote your app with popups once it's been installed? How do you know how every user organizes their apps? If the user launches your app often, why do you assume that they are having trouble finding and launching it from wherever it currently is?

Comment: may be this will help for you [counter by using shared preferences](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html)

Answer (score 1):

Write to a SharedPreferance  onCreate.  It won't be a very accurate count since onCreate is called at times other than only application start-up, but it'll be a reasonably good figure.

If you offer more details as to why you're doing this, you may get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks.The thing is I need the count of how many times the other applications have been used.So if an application on page 2 is used more than any app on page 1 i can show a message asking the user if he wants to move the app from page 2 to page 1 plz help

Comment: I would put all that in the question (rather than have it in this comment).  As far as I know there's no way to monitor this from an application. I suspect you'd have to write your own Home app, but I've never done it, so, I'm not 100% that it's doable.

Comment: is it possible to view from system log how many times has an app been used !! any idea

Answer (score 1):

Just, declare:

```
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private int appOpened;
```

Initialize in `onCreate(...)` :

```
prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();
```

count wherever you want (any where in `onCreate()` or any Method of your wish):

```
appOpened = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
appOpened++;

editor.putInt("counter", appOpened);
editor.commit();
```

Then you use `appOpened` variable to do your task.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a file which stores one number, not on the SD card but locally for your app. Then open this and increment the number in your onCreate method. You can also keep track of when they do other things but don't actually close it with onPause and onResume... There might be another way to save data without explicitly creating a file...

Comment: i need to count how many times the other apps have been used,not mine

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless your app is constantly running in the background, like a service - even then I don't know. But yeah, the question isn't very clear then.

Answer (score 0):

by using Flurry we can do this.

> The Flurry Android Analytics Agent allows you to track the usage and behavior of your Android application on users' phones for viewing in the Flurry Analytics system