# How do I count the number of times an Android application is used?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting application usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775242/counting-application-usage-in-android)

I would like to count the number of times an applications is used so that I may prompt the user to determine if she would like to move the application icon to a different page for more commonly used applications.